# Spring IOC DI with runtime parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm relativity new to IOC and DI, so I'm guessing that I am missing some high-level design principle here, but I cannot figure out how to get my architecture working.

I have a REST API endpoint that accepts two pieces of POST data: customer ID, and Type ID. The rest api then needs to return a set of data for that specific customer/type combo.

Here is a crude picture of what I am doing:
[image]

The controller is taking the entity IDs passed in via post data, and via a JPA repository getting the appropriate Entities for them.

I then construct a data generator object (that takes the entities as constructor parameters), and use that to handle all of the data gathering for the API.

**The Problem:** because the Data Generator takes the two dynamic constructor parameters, it cannot be DI'ed into the Controller, but instead must be made with `new`. Inside of the Data Generator, however, I need access to JPA repositories. The only way to get access to these repositories is via DI. I cannot DI however, as the object was `new`'ed not DI'ed by the IOC container.

Is there a way to architect this so that I don't have this problem? Am I breaking some rule regarding IOC? Do I have wrong assumptions somewhere? Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit: Pseudo code for Data Generator**

```
public class DataGenerator {
    private Customer customer;
    private Type type

    public DataGenerator(Customer customer, Type type) {
        this.cusomter = customer;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public generateData() {
        if(customer == x && type == y) {
            //JPA REPOSITORY QUERY
        } else {
            //DIFFERENT JPA REPOSITORY QUERY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question could be more clear, if would provide short code of generator.

Comment: Thanks for the input - pseudo code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have gotten confused somewhere along the line. You should have a `Service` that hits your repositories, and provide the information to the controller. One crude setup would be something like this.

```
@Controller 
public MyController {

    @AutoWired
    private DataService dataService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private DataGenerator readBookmark(@PathVariable Long customerId, @PathVariable Integer typeId) {
        return dataService.getData(customerId, typeId);
    }
}

@Service
public class DataService {

    @AutoWired
    private JPARepository repository;

    public DataGenerator getData(long customerId, int typeId) {
        Type typeDetails = repository.getType(typeId);
        Customer customerDetails = repository.getCustomer(customerId);
        return new DataGenerator(customerDetails, typeDetails);
    }
}
```

Comment: What If I need the DataGenerator to have something Injected into it. I updated my question to make this more clear. For example: The DataGenerator needs to have access to JPA repositories (as shown via comments), but because it is created with `new` the repositories cannot be injected.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with that query being ran in ```DataService```?

Comment: Every different Customer/Type combination will have a different query to run. I would like Data Generator to abstract this away from the user (possibly with some class hierarchies), as I think this will produce the best code. Perhaps IOC doesn't allow this...

Comment: Running completely different queries based on the ```customerId ``` and ```typeId``` seems pretty outlandish. Is the design behind this approach sound? If the queries vary so much, would it not be a better approach to have additional mappings in your ```Controller``` to account for the vastly different execution paths?

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately I am just consuming the DB - I didn't get any say in it's structure. If this wasn't an IOC paradigm I think that my approach would be solid. I would have an abstract class defining how to interact with the data, and then for each different customer/type there would be a subclass of that. The differences would be abstracted away as far away as possible and the code paths would only diverge right before the DB queries. I just don't know if this is the right way to do it in IOC/Spring

Comment: It appears to me at least, that you're over complicating things slightly. A ```Service``` (such as my crude ```DataService``` example) is used for handling business operations such as how to interact with the data. You should not be passing injected objects into pojos. The ```DataService``` itself should be able to provide what-ever data it is you need to the controller by using the ```JpaRepository``` and ```Customer```/```Type``` objects, that it should also be able to access.